# I have connection issue and its changing ip

Tags: mysql

I use **DB** 'Mysql 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24' and the **OS** is 'Ubuntu 18.04'

The DB server have local IP : 10.0.**211**.198

And For The application IP : 10.0.**214**.198

when I try connect form application server to db I get error in the connection but After I read it I found the mysql client change IP to Application IP as below screen

[image]

But when I try connect using telnet its successfully connected.

I try to remove db and reinstall it also try different client to connect and its same result.

Thank you

Comment: @mustaccio its different because I already allow remote access and check it with telnet

Comment: What does telnet have to do with MySQL authentication?

Comment: Nothing just test connectivity  telnet 10.0.211.198 3306

Comment: If "nothing", as you correctly point out, why do you use it to check MySQL authentication success?

Comment: @mustaccio I use it for test connection between servers not the authentication

https://www.crazydomains.com/help/check-mysql-with-telnet/

Comment: But your problem is with authentication!

Comment: I'm not sure I am confused because the error message return App IP not DB Ip

Comment: It tells you you're not allowed to connect to the database as root from your application server IP.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 attempts where 'root' is expected to have a password, then two where it is not.  Did someone change things meanwhile?

It is not "normal" to allow `root` to come in any way other than via "localhost".  Did someone `GRANT` access for root from elsewhere?  If not, then should you really be logging in as "root"??

`telnet` checks the connection.  However, that is not in question -- "Access denied" came from the server back to the client, hence the connection succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, I found the problem in my.conf

I change bind address from 172.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and finally its work

```
bind-adress= 0.0.0.0
```